# Regex pattern where end of the String matches

Tags: regex, string, match

I have the following problem. I want to search for the path of folders and files and my regex should ONLY match if the last part of the path (file or directory) includes my searchstring.

For example:

I want to search for 'hallo' in the following path's:

> 1. D:\Users\me\Documents\FindFile\hallo\
> 2. D:\Users\me\Documents\FindFile\hallo\bla\
> 3. D:\Users\me\Documents\FindFile\hallo\bla\bla 2\
> 4. D:\Users\me\Documents\FindFile\hallo\inside\
> 5. D:\Users\me\Documents\FindFile\hallo\inside\hallo nr2\
> 6. D:\Users\me\Documents\FindFile\hallo\inside\hallo nr2\well hallo.txt
> 7. D:\Users\me\Documents\FindFile\test\drin\das hallo\
> 8. D:\Users\me\Documents\FindFile\test\drin\hallo test\
> 9. D:\Users\me\Documents\FindFile\test\txt drin\test_hallo.txt

Now Path numbers 2, 3 and 4 should NOT be matched because they don't end with a 'hallo' in it. (For example 2 ends with 'bla' and not with 'bla hallo' or something that has 'hallo' in it)

I'm currently trying this with this regex: `.*hallo(\\|.+)` but it's not working.

You can check what I've done here. Lines 2 ,3 and 4 are highlighted and should be not:
https://regex101.com/r/eF3cU8/1

Comment: Trim the backslash on the right, split each string with the backslash and test only the last part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^.*hallo(?=\\$|[^\\]+).*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lO9eN9/2)

- `^` anchor at the start of the line (we are using the  `m` flag)
- `.*` any number of occurrences of any character
- `hallo` the literal text `hallo`
- `(?=\\$|[^\\]+)` a positive lookahead to confirm that either the next character is a slash followed by the end of the line, or there are no more slashes on the line
- `.*` any number of occurrences of any character
- `$` the end of the line

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If as you say - *ONLY match if the last part of the **path** includes my searchstring* - which would mean that example no. 9 shouldn't be matched either, this should do it:

```
hallo[^\\]*\\[^\\]*$
```

It matches `hallo` (your search string), **optionally** followed by any characters **but** `\`. Then followed by a `\`, and then again **optionally** followed by any characters **but** `\`

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eF3cU8/2).

Comment: @Keith Hall already answered my question. I explained it wrong because test_hallo.txt includes 'hallo' and thats what i'm searching for :) But thank you anyways!